# How to tidy VS terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, terminal, organization

I'm new and I just started coding so I'm allowed to ask dumb questions.

I don't know how to phrase this question but best way I can explain it is my terminal is cluttered and shows where the code is being saved ig? Idk what it's showing but every time I run it a line added before and after the program says

"a.b@ABs-MacBook-Pro CS shit % /usr/bin/python3 "/Users/a.b/Desktop/CS shit/Start.py"

Literally at the start and end every time I run the code, HELPPP

Tried google, not sure how to describe problem

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is normal, and it should be like this. I have the same thing every time I run the code.

```
PS C:\Users\user1\programs> & C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/user1/programs/test.py # at the start of the code
Hello World
PS C:\Users\user1\programs> # at the end of the code
```

I'm not sure if you can hide this, but you can try searching for some extensions or smth.

Comment: oh :(( I wish doing simple customizations like these was easier

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the code yourself. Considering VS Code is set with your preffered python version (you can see/change it on the bottom right) and you are in the folder of your script:

```
path/to/my_folder> python my_script.py
```